# Copying file between servers

Tags: bash, scp

i'm trying to create a simple script that will copy files from server1 to server 2  or from server 2 to server1(depends where i run the script from)
I created a script that should recognize on which server I am, take the source folder and destination folder and execute.

for example

```
sh script.sh /home/test /destest
```

should cop y files from test folder to the other server to destest folder

but something is not working for me, I keep getting

> No such file or directoryscp:

any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC1=$1
DEST=$3
BOX=$(hostname)
if [ $BOX=server1 ]; then 
sudo scp $SRC1 server2:\ $DEST

else
sudo scp -v $SRC1/* server1:\ $DEST
fi
```

Comment: Please fix your spelling errors and make sure your script exactly matches what you have. I doubt the script presented can produce the error message quoted. For mat the error message in backquotes, also, please.

Comment: Why are you putting an escaped space after the `:`? Do you really want to create a filename beginning with space on the remote server?

Comment: If you want to copy a whole folder, you should use the `-r` (recursive) option to `scp`. I also recommend using `rsync` instead of `scp`.

Comment: If the script is meant to be run using `bash`, use `bash script.sh` rather than `sh script.sh`. Or just type `./script.sh` and it will use the shebang line to find the interpreter.

Comment: You need spaces around `=` in `[ $BOX = server1 ]`

Answer (score 3):

Don't put a space after `server1:` and `server2:`.

You need a space around `=` in the `if` test.

You should almost always quote variables, in case the value contains whitespace, unless you actually want to split it into separate arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC1=$1
DEST=$3
BOX=$(hostname)
if [ "$BOX" = server1 ]; then 
    sudo scp "$SRC1" "server2:$DEST"
else
    sudo scp -v "$SRC1"/* "server1:$DEST"
fi
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, like `src1` instead of `SRC1` (to avoid the usual problems with reusing all-caps names with special meanings).

Answer (score 0):

This is my fixed script that is now working :)

```
#!/bin/bash
BOX=$(hostname)
if [ "$BOX" = server1 ]; then
sudo scp "$1" user@server2:\ "$2"
else
sudo scp "$1"/* user@server1:\ "$2"
fi
```

Comment: Is there a way to display total transferred bytes at the end of the script?